# javascript win counter for dice game

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            div.dice {
                float:left;
                width:32px;
                background:#F5F5F5;
                border:#999 1px solid;
                padding:10px;
                font-size:24px;
                text-align:center;
                margin:5px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function rollDice() {
                var die1 = document.getElementById("die1");
                var die2 = document.getElementById("die2");
                var status = document.getElementById("status");
                var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                var d2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                var wins = documentgetElementById("doubles");
                var diceTotal = d1 + d2;
                die1.innerHTML = d1;
                die2.innerHTML = d2;
                status.innerHTML = "You rolled " + diceTotal + ".";
                if (d1 == d2) {
                    status.innerHTML += " DOUBLES! You get a free turn!!";

                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="die1" class="dice">0</div>
        <div id="die2" class="dice">0</div>
        <button onclick="rollDice()">Roll Dice</button>
         <h2 id="status" style="clear:left;"></h2>
        <br>Wins:
        <h5 id="doubles" style="clear:left;"></h5>
        <br>
    </body>

</html>
```

I want to have it so the Wins is updated every time they roll doubles
 I still noob at this i was thinking it would be a simple line of code added after the 
    `status.innerHTML += " DOUBLES! You get a free turn!!";
    doubles.innerHTML =+ Wins;
    put var wins = document.getElementById("doubles");` ??? i know im doing something wrong any help would be awesome! Sincerely LM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/GkPEA/

`var wins = documentgetElementById("doubles");` has a typo and should be `var wins = document.getElementById("doubles");`

As for updating the win counter, you need to convert the element's value to an int before adding 1. However, I'd suggest storing the win count in a global variable as opposed to text in a DOM element.

```
if (d1 == d2) {
    status.innerHTML += " DOUBLES! You get a free turn!!";
    var winsCount = parseInt(wins.innerHTML) || 0;
    wins.innerHTML = winsCount + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see your problem. There is a typo on the line where you declare the variable `wins`, `documentgetElementById()` should be `document.getElementById()`. Start off with 0 in the wins  h5 and then every time the player wins do this code:

```
var previouswins = document.getElementById("doubles").innerHTML;
var presentwins = parseInt(previouswins, 10) + 1;
document.getElementById("doubles").innerHTML = presentwins;
```

That code creates a variable called `previouswins` that is basically just everything that's inside the `doubles` `h5`. Then we parse that as an integer, which means that javascript can now do math functions with it and then we add one. All that's left to do after that is write the new variable to the `doubles` `h5`.

Note that when using `parseInt`, you should always specify a *radix* (the base of number), as this does not default to 10 like you might expect. You can read more about this on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Description).

Comment: in 2013 you always should have specified the `radix` argument of `parseInt`. -1

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for pointing that out - fixed. Although I wonder why you didn't also bring up this problem with the accepted answer?